# can somone tell me why the program runs without getting any input?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I need to write a  program in C that gets a char array (sentence) and returns an array that each index contains the first letter of each word in the sentence.
I wrote an algorithm for it (which I hope is correct) but for some reason, when I activate the functions `printf()` and `gets()`, and run the program, the program runs without even printing or getting any input, and ends.

can you tell me the problem? I couldn't find it even with debugger:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *FirstLetters(char *sent)
{
    int i = 0, counter = 1, *firstchar, *p = sent, *q;
    while (*p != '\0')
    {
        if (*p == ' ')
            counter++; 
        p++;
    }
    firstchar = (char *)malloc(counter);
    q = firstchar;
    *q = sent[0];

    for (p = sent + 1, q = firstchar + 1; *p != '\0'; p++, q++)
    {
        if (*p == ' ')
        {
            *q = *p + 1;
            q++;
        }
    }
    return firstchar;
}

void main()
{
    char sentence[SIZE], *firstletter, *p;
    printf("Enter a sentence: ");
    gets(sentence);  
    firstletter = FirstLetters(sentence);
    printf("The result is: \n\n");
    puts(firstletter);
}
```

I tried getting the input for the sentence using for loop with `scanf_s`, but still, the program runs and ends without doing anything

Comment: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Comment: Turn up the warnings in your compiler and pay attention to them. https://godbolt.org/z/xdKczaEsd

Comment: *I tried using `scanf_s`* ... how did you try? It is not a drop-in replacement for `scanf`. Also MSVC reports 5 warnings and 3 errors from the posted code, i.e. the posted code cannot be run.

Comment: In C, you do not need and also you should not cast `void*` to another pointer type. It could hide errors. Or in your case, introduce new errors.

Comment: With `int i = 0, counter = 1, *firstchar` `firstchar = (char *)malloc(counter);` will not compile. You cannot assign a `char *` to an `int *`. Also, the whole pointer arithmetic on the `int *`s will go out of bounds quite fast.

Comment: @WeatherVane i know these functions are dangerous, but i am not speaking currently on the safety of the functions, just why the code as itself doesn't runs correctly?

Comment: As remarked, the posted code won't run at all. It's not the code you describe. Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows the problem. The best way to do that is by copy/paste the exact, whole program.

Comment: What is `SIZE`?

Comment: @mch I am not assigning char to an int, the (char *) tells the function to create an array of chars, and the (counter) tells the function malloc to set (counter) number of bytes in the array
since the sizeof(char)=1, i don't need to declare that in the function.

Comment: @WeatherVane but what is the reason it won't run?

Comment: You assign `char*` to `int*`. Not `char` to `int`. You explicitely cast the result of `malloc` to a `(char*)` and then assign to `firstchar` which is `int*`.

Comment: Did you read the man page for `gets`?  It tells you never to use it.  Use `fgets` instead.  `gets` is considered unsafe and is deprecated.

Comment: BTW: Do you remember, that strings are nul-terminated character sequences? You don't reserve any memory for a terminating 0 byte in `firstchar` and you also do not add a 0 byte. (Not to mention that your word counter fails if you have multiple spaces in a row.)

Comment: The reason it won't run is because the code does not compile, and there is no executable to run. Until we know what `SIZE` is, and what string you are entering, it's all supposition. But the compiler is *telling* you what is wrong. Don't even run the code until you have fixed all the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the function `gets()` is deprecated because it cannot be used safely. Use `fgets()` instead.
- `void main()` should be `int main(void)`
- `FirstLetters` does not compute the number of words correctly: if words are separated by more than one space, the count should not be incremented
- `firstchar`, `p` and `q` should be defined as `char *` variables, not `int *`.
- `firstchar = (char *)malloc(counter);` does not allocate space for the null terminator at the end of the `firstchar` string.
- `*q = *p + 1;` stores a `'!'` in the destination string, not the initial of the next word. You should write `*q = p[1];` for this, but the next character might also be a space.
- the null terminator is not stored.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *FirstLetters(const char *sent) {
    size_t counter = 0;
    char last = ' ';

    for (const char *p = sent; *p != '\0'; p++) {
        char c = *p;
        if (last == ' ' && c != ' ' && c != '\n')
            counter++;
        last = c;
    }
    char *firstchar = malloc(counter + 1);
    if (firstchar != NULL) {
        char *q = firstchar;
        last = ' ';
        for (const char *p = sent; *p != '\0'; p++) {
            char c = *p;
            if (last == ' ' && c != ' ' && c != '\n')
                *q++ = c;
            last = c;
        }
        *q = '\0';
    }
    return firstchar;
}

int main(void) {
    char sentence[SIZE];

    printf("Enter a sentence: ");
    if (fgets(sentence, sizeof sentence, stdin)) {
        char *firstletter = FirstLetters(sentence);
        printf("The result is: %s\n", firstletter);
        free(firstletter);
    }
    return 0;
}
```